# Splitting audio output to dynamics and headset

Tags: macos, audio, macbook

I'm using Macbook Pro(MD101) with OS X 10.8.3. How can I create two virtual audio devices one to work with Macbook's loud speakers and second with 3.5 jack? I heard that this is possible with SoundFlower, but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Audio Midi Setup.app, in the Utilities folder, and select 'Show Audio Window' under the Window menu, if the Audio Devices pane doesn't already appear...

In the lower left, click the <kbd>+</kbd> button, and select 'Create Multi-Output Device', and you should be good to go from there...

Comment: I've already tried that, but seems to me there is no thing which would help me from there.

Comment: I seem to have misread your query the first time...  No, it's not possible, as the built-in audio device is effectively hardwired to the headphone jack, routing sound to the speakers only if there's nothing plugged into it.